# Slurm: automatically shutdown job with inactive GPUs

Tags: gpu, slurm, hpc

Is it possible to configure Slurm in such a way that it automatically releases/shuts down a job with low-usage / inactive GPU(s)? So far the only option I find is to have a global job time limit but nothing smarter than that.

Comment: not that I know. however you could just run a script with Cron that does this. are you using task plugin?